# ImageView changes position in ConstraintLayout when reusing for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have some issues regarding the new Constraint Layout.
I am using RecyclerView, and the layout for the item is based on a Constraint Layout with 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView inside it.
In the design view, from Android Studio, everything looks fine, but on the actual device (a S5 with Lineage OS), the ImageView changes its position in some activities.
If I scroll down, the items are how they are supposed to be and when scroll back up, everything goes back to normal.
I mention that I am reusing the same layout file for 3 fragments with Recycler view.
This is the layout for 1 list item.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cont_item_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:background="@drawable/bottom_border"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_item_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="wqewqwewqeqw"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lbl_item_desc"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.008"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_item_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="weqweweqweweqeweqwe"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/lbl_item_title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_item_title"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lbl_item_save"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bookmarked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/lbl_item_desc"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />
```

On the phone, in the first fragment, everything is fine, no matter in which order I open it. But if I open the second or the third fragment, things are getting messed up.

[image]

Does anybody know what could influence the ImageView (the star) to move?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm facing with the same awkward situation. When i scroll down, everything is normal. But when i scroll up the right positioned image view loose its constraints. I changed constraintLayout to LinearLayout but the bug is still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer.
The parent layout, that was containing the RecyclerView, was using Constraint Layout as well, and it seems that there were some conflicts between them.
After changing the root layout to RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, everything went back to normal.